# How to configure a wireless router on a wired PEAP network

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, ethernet, peap

I tried plugging in a wireless router to a wired PEAP network to allow devices without ethernet ports to connect, but it doesn't work. Is a special type of wireless router required and are there any settings that need to be set on the router to configure it?